# how locale aware is preg_replace in php?

Tags: php

If I do, preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s-_]/','',$val) in a multi-lingual application, will it handle things like accented characters or russian characters? If not, how can I filter user input to only allow the above characters but with locale awareness?

thanks!

codecowboy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only useful information I can find is from [this page of the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.backslash.php), which states :

> A "word" character is any letter or
>   digit or the underscore character,
>   that is, any character which can be
>   part of a Perl "word". The definition
>   of letters and digits is controlled by
>   PCRE's character tables, and may vary
>   if locale-specific matching is taking
>   place. For example, in the "fr"
>   (French) locale, some character codes
>   greater than 128 are used for accented
>   letters, and these are matched by \w.

Still, I wouldn't bet that it's working as you want...

But, to be sure :

- maybe using [unicode matching](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php) would be better
- You'll probably have to try to be certain...

About unicode, the manual says this :

> Matching characters by Unicode
>   property is not fast, because PCRE has
>   to search a structure that contains
>   data for over fifteen thousand
>   characters. That is why the
>   traditional escape sequences such as
>   \d and \w do not use Unicode
>   properties in PCRE.

So, it might be a safer solution... curious about it, should I add ^^

Answer (score 1):

No, it will only match the ASCII character `A-Z`. To match any letter/number in any language, you need to use the [unicode properties of the regex engine](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php):

```
preg_replace('/[^\p{L}\p{N}]/', '', $string);
```